# Is there a way to render an anchor if the user has JavaScript disabled, but a button if the user has it enabled in SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am using SvelteKit and I am trying to render an anchor element that leads to a login page for users without JavaScript, but render a button that opens a Modal if the user has JavaScript enabled for a better UX. How can I do this?

Currently, I am implementing it like this (the component accepts the href and renders it as an anchor element styled as a button):

```
<Button
href="/login"
on:click={(e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 modalStore.trigger(modal);
}}
id="toggleAuthBtn"
>
Login
</Button>
```

However, this is not very accessibility friendly, as it IS being rendered as an anchor element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an anchor element in both cases. When showing the modal, you probably want the URL to change so it includes something that indicates that the modal is shown, so the user can bookmark/send the URL to someone else, and the modal will be shown immediately when going to that URL.

But nothing wrong with showing it as a button if you want, but then I would conditionally add a class to the anchor element that styles it to look like a button if the user has client-side JS enabled.

```html
<script>
    import { browser } from '$app/environment';
</script>

<a
    class:button={browser}
>
    ...
</a>

<style>
    .button{
        /* Make it look like a button here... */
    }
</style>
```